# How do you get centered content using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to follow a very basic example.  Using the [starter page and the grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), I was hoping the following:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p>Example text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

...would produce centered text.

However, it still appears on the far left. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you want the text inside the '<div class="span12">' centered, or do you want the whole '<div class="row">' div centered in the browser window?

Comment: Update the link to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: @Chloe people who care about HTML compatibility. `<center>` is deprecated in favor of `text-align: center` which, incidentally, is exactly what the bootstrap class `.text-center` wraps.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap 4, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388989/bootstrap-4-center-vertical-and-horizontal-alignment

Answer (score 698, accepted):

### This is for Text Centering (*which is what the question was about*)

For other types of content, see [Flavien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13099189/2812842).

**Update: Bootstrap 2.3.0+ Answer**

The original answer was for an early version of bootstrap. As of bootstrap 2.3.0, **you can simply give the div the class `.text-center`**.

---

**Original Answer (pre 2.3.0)**

You need to define one of the two classes, `row` or `span12` with a `text-align: center`. See http://jsfiddle.net/xKSUH/ or http://jsfiddle.net/xKSUH/1/

Comment: I've tried this for both row, and span12, but my table inside span12, inside row always sits left. Adding padding moves it to the center, but I want to center it in a responsive way. Can I do auto padding somehow?

Comment: I see that this is working but why should we need to define it.Are these not already defined?I am talking just about the text....

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma--the classes are defined, but last I looked, the `text-align: center` is not default on those classes. Typically the default is going to be `left` alignment.

Comment: for pre 2.3.0 the ```.pagination-centered``` also works :P saves you the keystroke of adding another class.

Comment: @Sarim: Actually, `pagination-centered` requires you to add another class to the html. My pre-2.3.0 answer only requires one to expand the property definition of a class already there. Also, if you look at the comments on the answer using `pagination-centered`, you will find some objections and warnings related to that. But if it works for you in your case--go to it! :-)

Comment: text-center in bootstrap 3, only works on small screens since .text-center is in a media query.

Comment: @cchiera `.text-center` is in the [type.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/type.less) file which should be importing in the main [bootstrap.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less) file (unless you have some custom configuration that it is missing in).

Comment: This is the .text-center {  text-align: center; } in chrome inspector . It is easy as text-align property . and it works fine .

Answer (score 240):

NOTE: this was [removed in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265253/centering-the-pagination-in-bootstrap#comment29641329_15265287).

---

Pre-Bootstrap 3, you could use the CSS class `pagination-centered` like this:

```
<div class="span12 pagination-centered">
    Centered content.
</div>
```

Class `pagination-centered` is already in bootstrap.css (or bootstrap.min.css) and has the only one rule:

```
.pagination-centered{text-align:center;}
```

With **Bootstrap 2.3.0.** just use class `text-center`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using this as its very specific to pagination (as inferred from the classname). It may clash with styles you apply on pagination and may not be compatible with future updates if bootstrap decides that this class needs to do more for centered pagination.

Comment: @lurii.k This makes EVERYTHING centered, including children. WHat if we just want to align the outer container but have everything inside it align left?

Comment: With bootstrap 2.3.0. just use css class .text-center

Comment: Greatest answer so far!

Work with bootstrap 2.3.2

Comment: It appears that Bootstrap 3.0.0 has removed this class. Using `.text-center` on the parent is the correct solution for this version.

Answer (score 155):

I guess most of the people here are actually searching for the way to *center the whole `div`* and not only the text content (which is trivial…).

The second way (instead of using text-align:center) to center things in HTML is to have an element with a fixed width and auto margin (left and right). With Bootstrap, the style defining auto margins is the "container" class.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span12">
        "Centered stuff there"
    </div>
</div>
```

Take a look here for a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/7788/

Comment: This is the correct answer, as officially documented here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts

Comment: @Qlimax Your link seems to be broken, I think this is what you wanted for 2.3.2: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts

Comment: @Sebastialonso I just fixed the deprecated dependency, thank you for reporting the issue

Comment: This won't work if you want to center a column. To center grid column, use `col-*offset-*`. for example `<div class="col-10 offset-1">` or `<div class="col-8 offset-2">`

Answer (score 55):

### **Bootstrap 5** (update 2021)

Bootstrap 5 still uses flexbox grid layout, so centering works the same way.

- `text-center` to center `display:inline` elements (ie: span, img)
- `mx-auto` for centering inside flex elements
- `offset-*` or `mx-auto` can be used to **center columns** (`.col-`)
- `justify-content-center` to **center columns** (`col-*`) inside `row`

### **Bootstrap 4**

"Centered content" can mean many different things, and Bootstrap centering has changed a lot since the original post.

**Horizontal Center**

**Bootstrap 3**

- `text-center` is used for `display:inline` elements
- `center-block` to center `display:block` elements
- `col-*offset-*` to center grid columns
- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42735943/171456) to center the navbar

[Demo Bootstrap 3 Horizontal Centering](http://www.codeply.com/go/QFFelXJfL6)

**Bootstrap 4**

- `text-center` is still used for `display:inline` elements
- `mx-auto` replaces `center-block` to center `display:block` elements
- `offset-*` *or* `mx-auto` can be used to center grid columns
- `justify-content-center` in `row` can also be used to center `col-*`

`mx-auto` (auto x-axis margins) will center `display:block` or `display:flex` elements that have a *defined width*, (`%`, `vw`, `px`, etc..). **Flexbox is used by default** on grid columns, so there are also various flexbox centering methods.

[**Demo** Bootstrap 4 Horizontal Centering](http://www.codeply.com/go/SOSvvKpLOc)

---

**Vertical Center**
--

Now that Bootstrap 4 is **flexbox by default** there are many different approaches to vertical alignment using: [auto-margins](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#auto-margins), [flexbox utils](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/), or the [display utils](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/) along with [vertical align utils](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/). At first "vertical align utils" seems obvious but these *only* work with inline and table display elements. Here are some Bootstrap 4 vertical centering options..

---

**1 - Vertical Center Using Auto Margins:**

Another way to vertically center is to use `my-auto`. This will center the element within it's container. For example, `h-100` makes the row full height, and `my-auto` will vertically center the `col-sm-12` column.

```
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-12 my-auto">
        <div class="card card-block w-25">Card</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Vertical Center Using Auto Margins **Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/akn5BYxQwn)

`my-auto` represents margins on the vertical y-axis and is equivalent to:

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
```

---

**2 - Vertical Center with Flexbox:**

[image: vertical center grid columns]

Since Bootstrap 4 `.row` is now `display:flex` you can simply use `align-self-center` on any column to vertically center it...

```
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-6 align-self-center">
                <div class="card card-block">
                 Center
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-danger">
                    Taller
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

or, use `align-items-center` on the entire `.row` to vertically center align all `col-*` in the row...

```
       <div class="row align-items-center">
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card card-block">
                 Center
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-danger">
                    Taller
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

[Vertical Center Different Height Columns **Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/GFgGl4YS27)

---

**3 - Vertical Center Using Display Utils:**

Bootstrap 4 has [display utils](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/) that can be used for `display:table`, `display:table-cell`, `display:inline`, etc.. These can be used with the [vertical alignment utils](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/) to align inline, inline-block or table cell elements.

```
<div class="row h-50">
    <div class="col-sm-12 h-100 d-table">
        <div class="card card-block d-table-cell align-middle">
            I am centered vertically
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Vertical Center Using Display Utils **Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/30DYTbq83o)

Comment: When using Grid layout I found that only the following combination of css would horizontally & vertically align a div inside a column so that the maximum height of the column also matched the largest column in the same row.  
`.className-of-inner-div  {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.className-of-Grid-column {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
}`

Comment: I'd upvote for each demo if I could. They're great. :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 36):

**Bootstrap 3.1.1** has a `.center-block` class for centering divs. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center.

> > Center content blocks Set an element to `display: block` and center via `margin`. Available as a mixin and class.

```
<div class="center-block">...</div>
```

Or, as others have already said, use the `.text-center` class to centre text.

Answer (score 29):

The best way to do this is define a css style:

```
.centered-text {
    text-align:center
}
```

Then where ever you need centered text you add it like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12 centered-text">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

or if you just want the p tag centered:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12 centered-text">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="centered-text">Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The less inline css you use the better.

Comment: Good one, I used this to center the buttons in a Bootstrap Modal footer.

Answer (score 14):

The class .show-grid is applying center aligned text in the example in the link.

You can always add `style="text-align:center"` to your row div or some other class I would think.

Comment: adding inline styles like this is often considered bad practice

Comment: I agree, and that's why I also said "or some other class" :)

Answer (score 12):

As of February 2013, in some cases, I add a "centred" class to the "span" div:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span9 centred">
      This div will be centred.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and to CSS:

```
[class*="span"].centred {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
}
```

The reason for this is because the span* div's get floated to the left, and the "auto margin" centering technique works only if the div is not floated.

Demo (on JSFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/5RpSh/8/embedded/result/

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5RpSh/8/

Comment: This is the best answer because it the div is centered and it is still responsive. Here is a fiddle for the demo. The one in the answer doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/r7Qgn/6/

Answer (score 9):

If you use Bootstrap 3, it also has built-in CSS class named **.text-center**. That's what you want.

```
<div class="text-left">
    left
</div>

<div class="text-center">
    center
</div>

<div class="text-right">
    right
</div>
```

Please see the example in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ucheng/Q4Fue/

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap 2.3 has a `text-center` class.

```
<p class="text-left">Left aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-right">Right aligned text.</p>
```

Comment: No, that's work only for text, the question is about the main container

Comment: "the question is about the main container" I don't see why you claim that (and see the accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

On my side I define new `CSS` styles ready to use and easy to remember:

```
.center { text-align: center;}
.left { text-align: left;}
.right { text-align: right;}
.justify { text-align: justify;}
.fleft { float: left;} /*-> similar to .pull-left already existing in bootstrap*/
.fright { float: right;}  /*-> similar to .pull-right already existing in bootstrap*/
.vab { vertical-align: bottom;}
.bold { font-weight: bold;}
.italic { font-style: italic;}
```

Is it a good idea? 
Is there any good practice for this?

Comment: slippery slope. css is supposed to remove styling concerns from the document structure. These, albeit indirectly, add them back. Maybe TBS sets a bad example with their `span12`s and the like

Comment: I agree with the slippery slope comment. I'd also add that the use of Twitter Bootstrap itself is arguably a slippery slope.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Bootstrap 2.0+

This can make the div centered to the page.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4 offset4">
        //your content here gets centered of the page
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not center the element. it puts the upper left corner of the element to 4 columns forward. centering means putting the exact center of the element to the center of the container element.

Answer (score 3):

Any text-align utility class would do the trick. Bootstrap has been using `.text-center` class for centering text for a long time now.

```
.text-center { text-align: center !important; }
```

Or you can create your own utilities. Some variations I've seen over the years:

```
.u-text-center { text-align: center !important; }
.ta-center { text-align: center !important; }
.ta\:c { text-align: center !important; }
```

Comment: Not a good design since pull-left and pull-right effects the element given the class. pull-center as you define, effects the childs of the element.

Answer (score 3):

You need to adjust with the `.span`.

Example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <!--/span-->
    <div class="span4" align="center">
      <div class="hero-unit" align="center">
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
        <form>
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> </span>
            <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
          </div>
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-key"></i> </span>
            <input class="span6" type="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /span -->
    <div class="span4"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /row -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

My preferred method for centering blocks of information while maintaining responsiveness (mobile compatibility) is to place two empty `span1` divs before and after the content you wish to center.

```
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span1">
    </div>

        <div class="span10">
          <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Reading Resources</h1>
            <p>Read here...</p>
          </div>
        </div><!--/span-->

    <div class="span1">
    </div>

</div><!--/row-->
```

Answer (score 2):

For Bootstrap version 3.1.1 and above, the best class for centering the content is the `.center-block` helper class.

Comment: yes it is wright now very themes and users use bootstrap versions greater than 3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 centered">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
       <div class="col-md-10">
           label
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do not use container-fluid in the main.

Comment: You have a `centered` class in your code that will create a lot of confusion

Comment: interesting approach, but for my particular webform css, this was a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Center-block is also an option not referred in above answers

```html
    <div class="center-block" style="width:200px;background-color:#ccc;">...</div>
```

All the class `center-block` does is to tell the element to have a margin of 0 auto, the auto being the left/right margins. However, unless the class text-center or css text-align:center; is set on the parent, the element does not know the point to work out this auto calculation from, so it will not center itself as anticipated.

So text-center is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one of the below types

1. Use the Bootstrap existing class `text-center`.
2. Adding a custom style, `style = "text-align:center"`.
3. Use a column offset:

   Example: `<div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-12"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I created this class to keep the  centered regardless of screen size while maintaining responsive features:

```
.container {
    alignment-adjust: central;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a class, text-center, for the div or tag which you want. I think it may work fine. It is a Bootstrap class for text align center.

Here are some text alignment Bootstrap classes:

```
text-left, text-right, text-justify, etc.
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
  <p>Example text.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried two ways, and it worked fine to center the div. Both the ways will align the divs on all screens.

**Way 1: Using Push:**

```
<div class = "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-push-4 col-md-push-4 col-sm-push-4 col-xs-push-4" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px">
    <h2>Grievance form</h2> <!-- To center this text, use style="text-align: center" -->
  </div>
```

**Way 2: Using Offset:**

```
<div class = "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offest-4 col-sm-offest-4 col-xs-offest-4" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px">
    <h2>Grievance form</h2> <!--to center this text, use style="text-align: center"-->
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Explanation**

Bootstrap will designate to the left, the first column of the specified screen-occupancy. If we use offset or push it will shift the 'this' column by 'those' many columns. Though I faced some issues in responsiveness of offset, push was awesome.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2018:**

In [Bootstrap 4.1.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/), content can be centered using class `mx-auto`.

```
<div class="mx-auto">
  Centered element
</div>
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer. Hope it helps someone

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class='d-flex flex-row justify-content-center'>
      <img     
        className='img-fluid'       
        src="<url>"
          />
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```