# How to center elements within a span with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, center

I would like to know how can I center the items in a span ( with bootsrap ) so as to have a good effect with mobile devices.

Thanks in advance

Comment: give us sample of your html code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get centered content using Twitter bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184141/how-do-you-get-centered-content-using-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about pagination-centered class

```
    <div class="myspan1 pagination-centered">
      <button class="myclass1">
        WHATEVER
      </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the desired effect