# Centering the pagination in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this code in pagination

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?p=0" data-original-title="" title="">1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="?p=1" data-original-title="" title="">2</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

But my `ul` is left aligned. Is there any way to center the `ul` wrt `div`?

I tried `margin: auto auto` and `margin :0 auto` they but didn't work.

Comment: With Bootstrap 3, you would have to wrap the `<ul class="pagination">...</ul>` inside a `<div class="text-center"></div>`.

Comment: Bootstrap has several versions... It would be helpful if you could mention which specific version you are using.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

#### Bootstrap has added a new class from 3.0.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="?p=0" data-original-title="" title="">1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="?p=1" data-original-title="" title="">2</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### Bootstrap 4 has new class

```
<div class="text-xs-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="?p=0" data-original-title="" title="">1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="?p=1" data-original-title="" title="">2</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### For 2.3.2

```
<div class="pagination text-center">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?p=0" data-original-title="" title="">1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="?p=1" data-original-title="" title="">2</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

<strike>Give this way:</strike>

```
.pagination {text-align: center;}
```

<strike>It works because `ul` is using `inline-block;`</strike>

#### <strike>Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/5L8fu/</strike>

---

<strike>Or if you would like to use Bootstrap's class:</strike>

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?p=0" data-original-title="" title="">1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="?p=1" data-original-title="" title="">2</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### <strike>Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/5L8fu/1/</strike>

Comment: i tried and it didn't work. there is no overididng all css i can see in firebug is from bootstrap and this one

Comment: Use `pagination-centered`. Both does the same, but this is better. See http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/5L8fu/1/

Comment: can you tell where in the docs they have reference to pagination-centered

Comment: See [Pagination](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#pagination), and in that **Alignment** section. *Add one of two optional classes to change the alignment of pagination links: .pagination-centered and .pagination-right.*

Comment: **Some people would like to watch the world burn with hit and run downvotes. Can they please clarify what's the problem with the answer?**

Comment: @Praveen .pagination-centered was removed in Bootstrap 3, use .text-center instead. No downvote from me, though :P

Comment: I don't know when drive-by downvoting became cool, but your first answer works for me so have an upvote.

Comment: `pagination pagination-centered` totally worked for me and looks clean

Comment: Is it a good idea to add Bootstrap 4 given that it is still in alpha?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 should be `<div class='d-flex'><ul class='pagination mx-auto'>...`

Comment: Add `<ul class="pagination pagination-lg justify-content-center">...` to solutions please. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/pagination/#alignment

Comment: @Денис Sure. Will do.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is wrong. It was obviously right at some point, but it's wrong now, at least for BS 4.x.  The correct answer is now to add justify-content-center to the ul: <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">

Comment: .dataTables_paginate .pagination {
 justify-content: center !important;
}

Comment: For BS 4.5, this is not correct. Alignment is now discussed in the [Pagination documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/pagination/#alignment) and [noobtw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43660921/1673550) is better.

Comment: @OllieBrown As this answer is written before Bootstrap 4.5 was released, it is very obvious that this is outdated. Would you like to update the answer, as that would be the right thing to do instead of complaining? If not, I'll update it tomorrow. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 86):

For both Bootstrap 3.0 and 2.3.2, to center pagination, the **.text-center** class can be applied to the containing **div**.

*Note:* Where to apply the **.pagination** class in the markup has changed between Bootstrap 2.3.2 and 3.0. See below, or read the Bootstrap docs on pagination: [Bootstrap 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination), [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#pagination).

**Bootstrap 3 Example**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="?p=0" data-original-title="" title="">1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="?p=1" data-original-title="" title="">2</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mynameiswilson/eYNMu/

**Bootstrap 2.3.2 Example**

```
<div class="pagination text-center">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?p=0" data-original-title="" title="">1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="?p=1" data-original-title="" title="">2</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mynameiswilson/84X3M/

Comment: also Bootstrap should document this.

Answer (score 83):

To centered the pagination in BS4, should add `justify-content-center` in `ul`:

```html
 <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
      <li class="page-item disabled">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

See [Pagination Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/pagination/) for further information.

Comment: should be the answer

Answer (score 34):

Using laravel with bootstrap 4, the solution that worked:

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="mx-auto">
        {{$products->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using Symfony and bootstrap4, working too ! thanks !

Answer (score 13):

**solution for Bootstrap 4**

You can use it 
 **Alignment**
use this class `justify-content-center`

Change the alignment of pagination components with [flexbox utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

and learn more about it [pagination](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 8):

The previously mentioned solutions for Bootstrap 3.0 did not work for me on 3.1.1. The pagination class has `display:block`, and the `<li>` elements have `float:left`, which means merely wrapping the `<ul>` in `text-center` alone does not work.  I have no idea how or when things changed between 3.0 and 3.1.1.  Anyway, I had make the `<ul>` use `display:inline-block` instead.  Here's the code:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination" style="display: inline-block">
        <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or for a cleaner setup, omit the `style` attribute and put it in your stylesheet instead:

```
.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And then use the markup previously suggested:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

This this, it worked for me:

**Style**:

```
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pagination li {
  display: block;
 }
```

**And blade**:

```
<div class="pagination">                                              
  {{ $myCollection->render() }}
</div>
```

Comment: Using the settings of your first definition, I created the class below and added it to the wrapping div above my pagination did the trick for me.

`.cs-list-paginator {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
`

Answer (score 6):

You can add your custom Css:

```
.pagination{
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It works for me:

```
<div class="text-center">
<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
   <li>
  <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get any of the proposed solutions to work with Bootstrap 4 alpha 6, but the following variation finally got me a centred pagination bar.

CSS override:

```
.pagination {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

No other combination of `display`, `margin` or class on the wrapping div seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

**In Boostrap 5 pagination centering**

```
        <ul class=" pagination justify-content-center ">;
```

Using:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/pagination/
and
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 1):

In v4.0.0-alpha.6:

```
<div class="text-center text-sm-right">
    <ul class="pagination d-inline-flex">...</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap 4 :

```
<!-- Default (left-aligned) -->
<ul class="pagination" style="margin:20px 0">
  <li class="page-item">...</li>
</ul>

<!-- Center-aligned -->
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center" style="margin:20px 0">
  <li class="page-item">...</li>
</ul>

<!-- Right-aligned -->
<ul class="pagination justify-content-end" style="margin:20px 0">
  <li class="page-item">...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This css works for me:

```
.dataTables_paginate {
   float: none !important;
   text-align: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if use **bootstrap**

**in blade page**

```
<div class="pagination justify-content-center">
   {{ $products->links() }}
     //or
   {{ $products->render() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
You can use the below code to center pagination
```

```css
.pagination-centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination-centered">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No need for custom class when there are helpers in bootstrap that will solve the issue.