# Center content in responsive bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm having trouble centering my content in the bootstrap navbar. I'm using bootstrap 3. I've read many posts, but the CSS or methods used will not work with my code! I'm really frustrated, so this is like my last option. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Navigation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
      <h1>Home</h1>

   </div>
     <!--JAVASCRIPT-->
   <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amk07fb3/

Comment: Especially for toggle, create a CSS class - .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translatex(-50%);
        }

Answer (score 463, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. You need to remove the `float: left` from the inner nav to center it and make it a inline-block.

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bdd9U/2/

**Edit:** if you only want this effect to happen when the nav isn't collapsed surround it in the appropriate media query.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bdd9U/3/

Comment: If you have problems with extra space below the links (if you're using a different background for active links for example) you can use: `.navbar .navbar-collapse { line-height: 0px; }`

Comment: I will recommend to not play with original bootstrap.css. Instead, create your own style.

Comment: In my case, I had to remove "flex" and replace with "inline-block," then it started working.

Answer (score 52):

The original post was asking how to center the collapsed navbar. To center elements on the normal navbar, try this:

```
.navbar-nav {
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

There's another way to do this for layouts that doesn't have to put the navbar inside the container, and which doesn't require any CSS or Bootstrap overrides.

Simply place a div with the Bootstrap `container` class around the navbar.  This will center the links inside the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <!-- here's where you put the container tag -->
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
    <!-- header and collapsed icon here -->
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <!-- links here -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- close the container tag -->
</nav> <!-- close the nav tag -->
```

If you want the then align body content to the center navbar, you also put that body content in the Bootstrap `container` tag.

```
<div class="container">
  <! -- body content here -->
</div>
```

Not everyone can use this type of layout (some people need to nest the navbar itself inside the `container`).  Nonetheless, if you can do it, it's an easy way to get your navbar links and body centered.

You can see the results in this fullpage JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bdd9U/231/embedded/result/

Source:
http://jsfiddle.net/bdd9U/229/

Comment: Hm, this solution doesn't seem to work anymore. Your example is left aligned now.

Comment: did not work for me, but appreciate the simplicity of your solution!

Answer (score 21):

For Bootstrap 4:

Just use

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
```

mx-auto will do the job

Comment: What if I want to justify at center also vertically ?

Comment: Works for bootstrap 5 also

Answer (score 13):

**Bootstrap 5 (Update 2021)**

The Navbar is still **flexbox** based in Bootstrap 5 and centering content works the same as it did with Bootstrap 4. [Examples](https://codeply.com/p/le1KAzjdWx)

**Bootstrap 4**

Centering Navbar content is easier is Bootstrap 4, and you can see many centering scenarios explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20362024/171456

**Bootstrap 3**

Another scenario that doesn't seem to have been answered yet is centering **both** the **brand *and* navbar links**. Here's a solution..

```
.navbar .navbar-header,
.navbar-collapse {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse  {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/1lrdvNH9GI

Also see:
[Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-and-right-aligned-items)

Answer (score 12):

This code worked for me

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

from the bootstrap official site (and, almost, like Eric S. Bullington said.

https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

the example navbar looks like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        ...etc
```

to center the nav, that what i've done:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="nav_center">
```

css:

```
@media (min-width:768px) { /* don't break navbar on small screen */
    #nav_center {
        width: 700px /* need to found your width according to your entry*/
    }
}
```

work with class="container" and navbar-right or left, and of course you can replace id by class. :D

Answer (score 4):

Seems like all these answers involve custom css on top of bootstrap. The answer I am providing utilizes only bootstrap so I hope it comes to use for those that want to limit customizations.

This was tested with Bootstrap V3.3.7

```
<footer class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2 text-center">
                <p>I am centered text<p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
 .navbar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/components/directives/navBar/navBar.scss"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><h5><a href="#/">Home</a></h5></li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li><h5><a href="#products">About</a></h5></li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li><h5><a href="#">Contacts</a></h5></li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li><h5><a href="#cart">Cart</a></h5></li>
            </ul>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

And css

```
.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus{
  background-color:white;
}
```

Modify according to your needs

Answer (score 1):

V4 of BootStrap is adding Center (justify-content-center) and Right Alignment (justify-content-end) as per: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#horizontal-alignment

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

it because it apply flex. you can use this code

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
    display: -ms-flexbox!important;
    display: flex!important;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

in my case it workded correctly.