# Align Bootstrap Navigation to Center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a problem with bootstrap 3 navigation, i have some content on the left, center and right. it seems there is no option for centering the navigation.

http://jsfiddle.net/29tQt/embedded/result/

I'm trying to get the links titled "center" to be in the center of the page, how can i achieve that ?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Center</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Center</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Center</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Right</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Right</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: No it's not, that question doesn't have any `navbar-right` content and the answer fails if we have `float:right` content @kba

Comment: Would you be ok with a non-css answer?  ie.  JS?

Comment: @sberry no i'm trying to do it with a valid css way, i know that i can do many hacks to make this work but i'm trying to do it with a valid practice.

Comment: @ra_htial: Well, isn't http://jsfiddle.net/29tQt/5/ pretty much what you want? Because that's the top answer from the other question.

Comment: @kba yes true, i just added an answer for that. my mistake

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, I added this code and it seems it fixed the issue:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Source**

[Center content in responsive bootstrap navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar)

Comment: helps me easy way.

Comment: Works great! Only thing is taht for some reason `display: inline-block` mess up the height of the menu, making the <ul> have a space on bottom. I had to set a fixed height to .navbar.
Anyone else had this problem? How do you solved it? thanks!

Comment: @vinigarcia87 This may be a bit late but I found that on `.navbar-collapse` the height is set to `auto !important` if you change this to the height of the menu items nested in it it will remove the gap. This may require further work to get it to display correctly on mobile.

Answer (score 5):

Add 'justified' class to 'ul'.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav justified">
```

CSS:

```
.justified {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
}
```

Now, calculate its 'margin-left' in order to align it to `center`.

```
// calculating margin-left to align it to center;
var width = $('.justified').width();
$('.justified').css('margin-left', '-' + (width / 2)+'px');
```

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/29tQt/4/)

[JSFiddle Embedded Link](http://jsfiddle.net/29tQt/4/embedded/result/)

Comment: This will cause disgusting behavior, the navigation will realign after document ready. Not recommended to style a website using javascript

Comment: It worked. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar-nav {
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   margin-left: 40%;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
   margin-right: -15px;
   margin-left: 0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bg8sE/embedded/result/)

Since You Have used the `float` property we don't have many options except to adjust it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .container:before, .container:after, .container-fluid:before, .container-fluid:after, .row:before, .row:after, .form-horizontal .form-group:before, .form-horizontal .form-group:after, .btn-toolbar:before, .btn-toolbar:after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:before, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after, .nav:before, .nav:after, .navbar:before, .navbar:after, .navbar-header:before, .navbar-header:after, .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-collapse:after, .pager:before, .pager:after, .panel-body:before, .panel-body:after, .modal-footer:before, .modal-footer:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table-cell;
}

ul.nav {
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 240px;
}
```