# how to get my menu items to center in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, text-align

I have a simple bootstrap nav menu. It works great, but when it collapses, I want to be able to un-float the menu items, and have them become center aligned in the dropdown menu when they are in `@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {}` and below.

As of now the items are either staying floated, or when I un-float them and text align center, they are hard right aligned but worse, the collapse stays open no matter what size the browser.

**HTML:**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand white">Bab's Kitchen</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
       </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav {
    float:right;
}
.nav ul li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top:17px;
    margin-right:15px;
    font-size:14px;
    float: left;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:purple;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'cylburn';
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
    .nav ul li {
        font-size:20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .nav ul li {
        font-size:12px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top:18px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this correctly, you want something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

There are a few Stackoverflow articles that can point you further in the right direction and offer more explaination.

> [Align navigation to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980660/bootstrap-3-align-navigation-to-center)
>
> [Center content in responsivebootstrap navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar)
>
> [@Media min-width & max-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550541/media-min-width-max-width)

Hope this helps.

Comment: that is close. Exactly what you did EXCEPT I want them to not float, stack vertically and remain centered. A centered list in other words.

Comment: @user2684452 oh, maybe try display: block; instead of display: inline-block;