# How do I center my navigation links and image in my navigation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
header[role="banner"] {
      #logo-main {
        display: block;
        margin: 20px auto;
    
      }
    
}
    
#navbar-primary.navbar-default {
      background: transparent;
      border: none;
      .navbar-nav { 
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        > li {
          display: inline-block;
          float: none;
    
          > a {
    
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-right: 30px;
    
            }
        }
      }
}  
.collapse .navbar-collapse{
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    
<title>Blog Template for Bootstrap</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
    
<body>
  
  <div class="container"> 
    <header role="banner">
      <img id="logo-main" src="https://s3-us-west-        
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse" >
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#" >Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    </header><!-- header role="banner" -->
  
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    
  <div class="blog-header">
            <h1 class="blog-title">The Bootstrap Blog</h1>
            <p class="lead blog-description">The official example template of creating a blog with Bootstrap.</p>
          </div>
    
  <div class="row">
    
            <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
    
              <div class="blog-post">
                <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
                <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>
    
                <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that's supported and styled with Bootstrap. Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
                <hr>
                <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
                <blockquote>
                  <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong> ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </blockquote>
                <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
                <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
                <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
                <pre><code>Example code block</code></pre>
                <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
                <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
                <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                <ul>
                  <li>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</li>
                  <li>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</li>
                  <li>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</li>
                </ul>
                <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
                <ol>
                  <li>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</li>
                  <li>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</li>
                  <li>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</li>
                </ol>
    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.</p>
  </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
     
</body>
</html>
```

I need help centering the navigation links and the image "logo thing" at the top. I have tried several different things and I cannot find the solution. I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong I have been debugging for hours trying to figure it out. If someone could help me I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3: Align navigation to center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980660/bootstrap-3-align-navigation-to-center)

Answer (score 0):

On around line 23 in your css change:

```
header[role="banner"] {
    #logo-main {
        display: block;
        margin: 20px auto;

    }

}
```

to:

```
header[role="banner"] {
   display: block;
   margin: 20px auto;
   text-align:center;
}
```

or if you still want #logo-main change css to:

```
#logo-main {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and your html around line 67 change

```
<header role="banner">
```

to:

```
<header id="logo-main">
```