# Center contents of NavBar - BootStrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am trying to center the contents of the Nav Bar however, I cannot get it work properly

I think everything seems to be more left aligned than center but i havent used float:left anywhere

I am trying to Center the **Image and Navigation**

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Soni's Computer Repair</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="Final.png"/></a>

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>


                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <h6 class="text-center">Copyright &copy; Soni Computer Repairs</h6>
                <p class="text-center">www.SoniRepairs.com</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS: This is the CSS code

```
.nav, .navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.container img {
    height:100%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    .navbar-nav, .container img{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        float:none;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar

Answer (score 0):

HTML: I moved the navbar-brand inside the ul

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="Final.png"></a><li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS: I added these 3 lines

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav { float: none; }
    .navbar-nav>li { float: none; display: inline-block; }
    .navbar>.container .navbar-brand, .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand { float: none; display: inline-block; }
}
```

It's working this way for me. Enjoy =)