# How do I center the following navbar in Boostrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, center-align

I have a navigation bar that looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I just wanted to center the items in the list. I tried:

```
.navbar-default {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

But no luck.

Comment: Maybe you have to use margin: auto auto;

Comment: Your question has already answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar

Comment: You can always abuse your privilege of flexbox :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that should help you `margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 1):

You can set `margin:0 auto;` to the navbar style as the other answer suggests, or you can also add the bootstrap `container` class to it which basically does the same thing for you.