# Solution for align bootstrap navigation(links) to the center

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating bootstrap site in which i have nav class which by default left side of the page but i want it to align it in the center ( i tried using align-text,align-itm then using bootstrap class row and col-md-4 but still no problem solved)

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Landing Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MylandingSS.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity=      "sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<!----------------HEADER------------------------------>
<div class="navbar-header navbar-brand header"><h1 class="navbarheader">IamMandar</h1></div>
<!------------------LINKS----------------------------------->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<ul class="nav nav-pills "><!---------to be centered------------->
<li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

***css***

```
@charset "utf-8";
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
        }
.navbar.navbar-default{
    background-image:none;
    background-color:rgba(89,63,127,0.79);
    border:none;
}
.navbarheader{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:-10px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
.nav ul{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center content in responsive bootstrap navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar)

Comment: @ jpaljasma no its not duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use center-block class

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills center-block ">
      <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

or else try using text-center am not expert but try this :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/davidcochran/pen/rcHae) 
**Html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
  </div>

 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li class="social pull-right"><a href="#">Social Links</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**css:**

```
.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `text-align: center` on the parent `.nav`, then negating the `float` on the nested `li` elements, while declaring a `display: inline-block` with custom a css rule, will align the list items center.

**CSS**

```
.nav.nav-pills>li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
ul.nav.nav-pills {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
        }
.navbar.navbar-default{
    background-image:none;
    background-color:rgba(89,63,127,0.79);
    border:none;
}
.navbarheader{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:-10px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
.nav ul{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.nav.nav-pills>li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
ul.nav.nav-pills {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Landing Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MylandingSS.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity=      "sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<!----------------HEADER------------------------------>
<div class="navbar-header navbar-brand header"><h1 class="navbarheader">IamMandar</h1></div>
<!------------------LINKS----------------------------------->
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Might also be better to move the logo mark-up into the same row as the navigation and adjust columns accordingly. Just play around with it, you may find a layout that will require fewer custom styling and retain a better responsive layout all round.

Answer (score 0):

use the bootstrap class `row` and use the second `.class col-md-6` `.col-md-offset-3`

[JSbin](http://jsbin.com/nasadu/edit?html,css,output)

***HTML***

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MylandingSS.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity=      "sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <!----------------HEADER------------------------------>
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-brand header"><h1 class="navbarheader">IamMandar</h1></div>
     <!------------------LINKS----------------------------------->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>  
  </div>

  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

***css***

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
        }
.navbar.navbar-default{
    background-image:none;
    background-color:rgba(89,63,127,0.79);
    border:none;
}
.navbarheader{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:-10px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
.nav,.navbar-nav{
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;

}
```