# How can I set my bootstrap menu in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is My bootstrap menu:

[image]

How can I align this menu on center?
here is my html code-

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>            
    </ul>
```

Comment: Try `<ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">`

Comment: not working...@Pugazh

Comment: Possible Duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar)