# How to center the contents of a navigation bar in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've looked for other answers, and found plenty about adjusting the #nav tag to change it to display: inline-block, as well as everything else I've found on similar SO questions, but nothing seems to work. Here's what it sits at now.

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>MANHammer Studios</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Do you have a wireframe/mockup of the layout you're looking to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center content in responsive bootstrap navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
div#myNavbar.collapse.navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

[Check working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/5mfvj9v2/7/)

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that worked exactly as I needed it to. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar{
    text-align: center;
}
```

is probably what you want?

Comment: I have attempted adding this, and it does not center the navbar's contents; they remain left-aligned. The same applies for trying align-content and align-items.

Comment: Have you checked if bootstrap dont override this? Or with !important flag?