# How to horizontally center a navbar in ASP.Net Core MVC Web app?

Tags: css, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to horizontally center a navbar in an ASP.Net Core MVC Web app. I have tried a ton of different things, but nothing is working.

Left and right justify work as expected. However, there is no obvious option for navbar-center (or something equivalent). Since Bootstrap is included in VS2017, I want to modify the CSHMTL - not .css.

There must be an easy way to do this. What am I missing?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:white; border-color: white">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>


        <!-- This is what I want to center. Navbar-right and navbar-left work perfectly. -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="background-color:white; border-color: white">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" style="background-color: white;  border-color: white">
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a asp-action="Create">Create</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ?

```
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not going to get away from not modifying the CSS, basically you can override it with the Site.css in the site or modify directly in the bootstrap css

[Center content in responsive bootstrap navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 0):

just Delete in file : **nav-menu.component.css**

`.main-nav {
        height: 100%;
        width: calc(25% - 20px);
    }`