# Center Bootstrap navbar title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for handle my `Bootstrap navbar title` and I don't overcome to center my tag.

My script for this part looks like :

```
<style>
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
</style>

<!-- #################### -->
<!-- Upper navigation bar -->
<!-- #################### -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand"> Choix du logiciel </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I would like to center : `Choix du logiciel`

[image]

I already read this post : [Center content in responsive bootstrap navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar)

But I don't find a way to make what I want :/

I think that it's not hard, but up to now it's not a success.

Thank you

Comment: So you're saying that adding `text-align:center;` to your navbar doesn't working right?

Comment: Yes, I forgot this line when I wrote my question. I would like to center this sentence but none effect up to now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** : It should work with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y1j95tm7/2/)

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        display: block;
        text-align:center;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-header{
  float: none; 
}
```

Comment: I don't see the difference xD

Comment: I've edited, it should be <style> instead of <script> in the beginning

Comment: Oh sorry, I added manually the first `<style>` tag and I make an error ! In my script, it's `<style> .. </style>` ;)

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

take `text-align: center;` out from your css `.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-header.navbar-brand {..}` and move it to

```
.navbar-header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

will fix it.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-header.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!-- #################### -->
<!-- Upper navigation bar -->
<!-- #################### -->
<div class="wraper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="navbar-header bg-yellow">
            <a class="navbar-brand bg-red"> Choix du logiciel </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I had another css file that's why some answers didn't work. Now it's okay with your answer ;)

Comment: @Deadpool a good way to debug is put some background color to each container, so you can see each block. =D

Comment: I take your idea and I will make this process next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this css:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change inline block to just block.

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put text-align:center on .navbar-header. It must work.

Your a tag must be display block so your text inside tag can be centered.

You can put display:block on a tag too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding display:inline-block to .navbar-brand may fix it.
And also text-align:center to .navbar-header

Answer (score 0):

Check this and see please

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with inbuilt bootstrap class '[.justify-content-center](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navs/#horizontal-alignment)', but will be applicable on bootstrap versions v4.4 and above

Can be applied to a nav component like below

```
 <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-center">
    <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
 </nav>
```