# How to center a bottom navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hello I added a bottom navigation bar in HTML and CSS code on my webpage but I want have that centered on the bottom of the website any help and solutions is greatly appreciated I have attached screenshots of the HTML, CSS codes and the webpage of where I have my navigation bar currently in the left hand side thanks very much in advance.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">Facebook Page</a>
</div>
```

HTML navbar code

[image: HTML navbar code]

CSS navbar code

[image: CSS navbar code]

webpage navbar

[image: webpage navbar]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center content in responsive bootstrap navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace your CSS code with below css code:

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.navbar a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

and your HTML with this code:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
     <a href="#">Facebook Page</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this code will work as you expect ..

Comment: I did the updated code that you told me about and It works guys again thanks so very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add to .navbar:

```
text-align:center;
```

Delete from .navbar a:

```
float: left;
```

Update in .navbar a:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #DDA0DD;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home" class="active">About</a>
  <a href="#news">Contact</a>
  <a href="#contact">Facebook page</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Bottom Navigation Bar</h1>
  <p>Some text some text some text.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

How to center a nav-bar at the bottom of a page

[image: How to center a nav-bar at the bottom of a page]

Comment: Please don't post code in an image but as text in a code block.