# Perfect center align horizontally with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There are some options I can choose from when it comes to horizontal center alignment with Bootstap.

I can either use `offset` class or use blank `span` class as a placeholder.
One other option can be using custom alignment like the following

```
.center {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

None of these options solve my issue because the content of the div container has to fill up the width by 100%.

Let's say I have the following

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4 offset4">
        <button class="btn">1-1</button>
        <button class="btn">1-2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the buttons do not fill up the whole div space of `span4`, I won't get the real center alignment. Perhaps, I can make the content stretch to 100% but I don't know if this is any good practice.

Here I have a canvas to play with. [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/aNokOgu/2/edit)

Comment: Adding your `.center` class should work.  What happens when add that class to the buttons?

Comment: It doesn't do it..thanks for your interest

Comment: This question is out-of-date for 3.x and 4.x see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42483682/171456

Answer (score 7):

Since you have inline elements you can just use the `.text-center` class on the span, also your're probably better off using offsets than empty elements:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4 offset4 text-center">
    <button class="btn">1-1</button>
    <button class="btn">1-2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated demo: http://jsbin.com/ayuFEhO/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

You don't need add a new class, if you want horizontal align this buttons, just use `.text-center` here is a bin http://jsbin.com/UVeGejO/1/edit

Obs: `text-center` class already exist on twitter's bootstrap code.