# How can I vertically center my bootstrap columns within their rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble vertically centering both my text `id="WhatIsMasterRow"` and image `id="WhatIsMasterPhoto`. I've tried wrapping it in a `.container` and using the bootstrap `center-block`, as well as some other centering classes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<body>
    <!-- What is Master Page -->
    <div class="row" id="WhatIsMasterRow">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="WhatIsMasterText">
            <div class="row-text", id="SubHeaderTextLeft"> What is a Master? </div>
            <div class="row-text", id="RegularTextLeft"> Test Text  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 center-text">
            <img id="WhatIsMasterPhoto" src="Resources/Images/Peter-Limmer-boots-2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I've tried using `margin: 0 auto;` as well, but it's not working.

```
.col-md-2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Please, create JSFiddle - that will speed up the process of helping You. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get centered content using Twitter bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184141/how-do-you-get-centered-content-using-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: I've tried all the methods in the above thread, hasn't been able to work. I'll work on a JSFiddle in a bit, I'm trying a major overhaul right now. Experimenting with containers. Sorry for the delay and thanks for the intended help!

Comment: fix the width of the div to a desired value and set its margin from left to the middle of the page that you are designing...
don't do margin:0 auto; 0 auto means that the top and bottom margins are 0 and the left and right margins are set automatically according to the width of the device on which the page is being viewed. 
make it margin: 0 something px;
it will work for you

Comment: Ok here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2LKXQ/1/. I'm just having trouble with the vertical align. Horizontal isn't a problem anymore.

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471973/how-can-i-vertically-center-my-bootstrap-columns