# How to center content within columns on Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<div class="article-quiz-content.container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6.quiz-cols">
            <div class="true-placeholder">
                <a class=icon-true-shape amenitie_icon" href="#" data-answer="true">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=col-xs-6.quiz-cols">
            <div class="false-placeholder">
                <a class="icon-false-shape amenitie_icon" href="#" data-answer="false">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which leads to this:

[image]

I need those icons to be in the center of the columns.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please post the raw HTML.

Comment: Still not proper HTML. Also, it looks like you have custom CSS, so please include that as well. You need to include everything relevant to the piece you're asking about.

Comment: That's named JADE. It's an engine.

Comment: Which is all fine and well, but you need to provide the full and proper HTML output from the engine, especially since you didn't tag the post with JADE.

Comment: Another dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184141/how-do-you-get-centered-content-using-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your css:

```
.quiz-cols{
   text-align: center;
}

.amenitie_icon{
  display: inline-block;

}
```

Inline-block element float to center if container has `text-align: center`

Comment: There are Bootstrap styling classes that can likely be used. No additional, custom CSS should be required.

Comment: text-center to the container, or center-block to the content (if is a block element)

Answer (score 2):

Just add class `text-center` to your columns (.col-xs-6)

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

EDIT: after you changed markup you need to add it to placeholder divs