# How do I center an image in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to horizontally center an image in the carousel of Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6.

It doesn't seem to work in any way I've tried, including using `center-block`.

Here's what I've tried so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJdjQg?editors=1100

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`center-block` has been replaced by `mx-auto` in Bootstrap 4. `mx-auto` represents auto x-axis margins (margin=left: auto; margin-right: auto) so it 
can be used to center `display:block` or `display:flex` elements.

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="https://unsplash.it/200/200" alt="First slide">
</div>
```

[More on Centering in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42483682/171456)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
.carousel-item img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```