# Center card vertically on background using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just to make it clear before flagging as repost,
all this doesn't work :
[How to center cards in bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031224/how-to-center-cards-in-bootstrap-4)
[How to align an image dead center with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879955/how-to-align-an-image-dead-center-with-bootstrap)
[Centering the image in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219951/centering-the-image-in-bootstrap)
[How can I center an image in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226511/how-can-i-center-an-image-in-bootstrap)
[How do I center an image in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744803/how-do-i-center-an-image-in-bootstrap)
[How to align a <div> to the middle (horizontally/width) of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-horizontally-width-of-the-page)
[How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Having said that, my issue is simple, I have two divs, the background div and the card div from bootstrap. mx-auto will center vertically just fine, however impossible to unfix from the top the card. So that I also have space above and below the card. I've tried all m and p classes. As well as custom classes. Could someone help me please. I would like my card to be in the middle of the screen.

```
<div class="bg">
<div class="card card-design success-design mx-auto">
<div class="card-body">
```

Now it looks like this:

```
ooooxxxoooo
ooooxxxoooo
ooooooooooo
ooooooooooo
```

I would like :

```
ooooooooooo
ooooxxxoooo
ooooxxxoooo
ooooooooooo
```

Comment: You "images" show that you want to center it vertically, but you're talking about "horizontally".

Comment: well this is the limit of language, I thought about it, and it seems that both can be true at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

h3, h4, p, a, label {
        color: #001f3f;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('exemple.png');

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* i added following code */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.card-design {
        background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.7);
        width: 23rem;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.success-design {
        background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.8);
}

.nbr-apt {
        font-size: 220%;
        font-weight: 100;
}

.rdv {
        font-size: 160%;
}

.num {
        font-weight: bold;
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="bg">
                <div class="card card-design success-design mx-auto">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title"> bla bla bla</h3>
                        <h4 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"> bla bla bla</h4>
                        <h4 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"> bla bla blam</h4>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <p class="card-text nbr-apt">Merci bla bla bla</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: with 3 line code.  i added  in `.bg { }` i showed there.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use some CSS to get the body to stretch to full height, so you can center the card, this is an example using [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.card {
 padding: 1rem;
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">I am a card</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this made my background image stop being diplayed beyond the card. However the card is still attached to the top.

Comment: could you provide a code example? maybe codepen. It would help better understand the issue

Comment: here is a codepen but the generated display is false of course https://codepen.io/ilanoh/pen/rodvVM

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Bootstrap 4` then you should utilize its utility classes.

Just add `d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center` classes to the root `div` and its content will be centered horizontally and vertically:

```css
.bg {
  background-color: #fff0f0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.card {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bg d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">My card</div>
    <div class="card-body">Some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```