# how to align text at center using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have used Twitter Bootstrap to align text and image side by side. Can you please give an idea how to align text in the center.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <a href="ghfhg"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color: rgb(72, 168, 237); font-size: 32px; box-sizing: content-box; line-height: 80px; text-align: center; width: 80px; height: 80px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(224, 231, 237);"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        sdsad
    </div>
</div>
```

I have already tested text-center it does not work very well:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6bzm.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get centered content using Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184141/how-do-you-get-centered-content-using-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive your result with the *Bootstrap 4* classes `d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:80px">
      <a href="ghfhg"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color: rgb(72, 168, 237); font-size: 32px; line-height: 80px; text-align: center; width: 80px; height: 80px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(224, 231, 237); margin-right: 5px;"></i></a>
      sdsad
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4rLj200m/9/

Comment: thankyou for your reply. it does not work very well.

Comment: any examples,sorry still new.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i have tested it.it works. but there is so much gap between 2 classes?

Comment: the bootstrap-classes `col-*-*` are responsive and will change width as your screen size changes, put both elements in one col and then control the spacing with margins. I changed the code above

Answer (score -1):

Just add the text-center class to the parent element.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <a href="ghfhg"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color: rgb(72, 168, 237); font-size: 32px; box-sizing: content-box; line-height: 80px; text-align: center; width: 80px; height: 80px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgb(224, 231, 237);"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
        sdsad
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect copy :-) +1

Comment: thankyou for your reply. it does not work very well.

Comment: It should work. This is how I align my texts. You probably have asigned different css for your page. Try it in a clean page and you will see that it works.

Comment: I know what is your problem. you have used col-sm-2 which has not enough spaced. if you use more columns so that the contents will have more space to put the text, you will see that it is actually centered. you code just do not have enough space to see the difference